# Java large list of object based on different conditions and business rules

Tags: java, list, algorithm, spring-boot, sorting

Java : I have a large list of `products` object from MySQL DB. Now this has to be sorted and listed based on various rules.

For example:

The list has to be sorted based on the following conditions

1. Location Id of `user` and `product` has to be matched and this should the top priority in the listing. (Changes depending on the user location)
2. `Featured` product has to be take the next priority.
3. Any `new preference` in future should be accommodated as next in the list

Currently this is achieved by monolithic way by fetching objects from DB based on different conditions nd appending the list, but maintaining the redundancy (same products fall under multiple categories has to be managed) and when the list grow relatively large this will not be scalable.

I'm looking for an algorithmic way or any best approach

To keep it short I want to list products like how Amazon or any shopping platform lists based on different business rules depending on the user.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's wrong with and `order by` in the query, especially given the example of amazon listings.

Comment: Hi Federico, Order by can do the job but what is required is say if a user live in CityA , I will find product in his/her state then country and many business rules which is not just solved by simple sorting.

Comment: That can be done with `where` and `join`. But honestly, it's hard to help without knowing exact business rules and exact table structures. So I have to be vague :)